# show selected option in Select

Tags: dart, html-select, dart-webui

The HTML file has select element that is populated from a list of states. I need to show a particular state, FL, as selected entry.

```html
<select id='mystate'  template iterate="x in myStatesList">
  <option>{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Tried following in dart file but it does not work:

```dart
inserted() {
  var x = query('#mystate') as SelectElement;
  x.options.selectedIndex = 10; 
}
```

Also tried calling function in option that returned 'selected' as follows:

```html
<option {{gv(x)}}> {{x}} </option>
```

and in dart

```dart
String gv(x) {
  if(x=='FL'){            
    return 'selected';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your `inserted()` function should have been :

```dart
inserted() {
  var x = query('#mystate') as SelectElement;
  x.selectedIndex = 10; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed html to:

```html
<option selected={{gv(x)}}>{{x}}</option>
```

and dart code to:

```dart
bool gv(x) {
  if(x == 'GA'){            
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and now it works!